# Bind a delete function on a dynamic row

Tags: jquery

I want to be able delete a dynamically created row when clicked on a X.

I am able to delete the first row by listening for a click

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
 $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
update_total();
});
```

However it does not work on subsequently created rows.
This is how I create the row

```
$('#addservice').click(function(){
  var $row = $('<tr valign="top" class="item-row"><td width="30"><a class="delete" title="Remove row">X</a></td><td width="410"><input name="customFieldName" type="text" size="50" id="customFieldName" /></td><td align="center"><input name="customFieldOurCost" type="text"/></td><td width="130" align="center"><input name="customFieldQuantity" type="text" size="10" class="qty" id="customFieldQuantity" /></td><td width="130" align="center"><input name="customFieldPrice" class="cost" type="text" size="10" id="customFieldPrice" /></td><td width="130" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="GST" checked="checked" class="gst" /></td><td width="130" align="center"><span class="exprice">$00.00</span></td><td width="130" align="center"><span class="incprice">$00.00</span></td></tr>').insertAfter(".item-row:last");


  bind($row);
  });


  function bind($row) {
                    $row.find('.cost').blur(update_price);
                    $row.find('.qty').blur(update_price);   
                    $row.find('.gst').click(update_price);
                    $row.find('input[name="customFieldName"]').autocomplete({
                        source: "DataQueries/LoadServices.asp",
                        minLength: 2
                    });
                    $row.find('input[name="customFieldName"]').blur(function() {
                        $.get('DataQueries/FetchQuantity.asp?ServiceName=' + encodeURI($row.find('#customFieldName').val()), function(data) {

                            $row.find('#customFieldQuantity').val(data); 
                        });
                        $.get('DataQueries/FetchPrice.asp?ServiceName=' + encodeURI($row.find('#customFieldName').val()), function(data2) {

                            $row.find('#customFieldPrice').val(data2); 
                        });

                    });
```

Thanks

Comment: use delegation, e.g: `$('table').on('click','.delete',function(){...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use event delegation, something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
  update_total();
});
```

You don't have to use `document` as the selector, any common parent element will work.  What this does is bind a click handler to the parent element (which needs to be static and not dynamically added/removed during the life of the DOM) which receives click events that "bubble up" from child elements.  It then applies a filter to those events (`'.delete'`) to only invoke itself on events from specific child elements, and executes the function.

That way any elements added after the fact will still be caught by the filter, since their events will reach the common parent element.

Comment: This works perfectly BUT how to do you stop the first row being deleted as well?

Comment: @Saj: Presumably if there's a raw that should never be deleted then you'd use different markup in that row, such as not giving it a `.delete` element or not giving it the `item-row` class.  Beyond that it's not really clear what you mean, at least not without seeing your markup.

Comment: Sometimes the most simplest of answers are the best. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

See, the events for the elements which are created during the run time can be registered only by using event delegation.

Try,

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function() {
 $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
update_total();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your click action with a live click action -

```
$('.delete').live('click' ,function() {
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
});
```

This will add that click action to any new dom element matching delete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the event to the closest static parent.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() { // delegate to document
  $(this).closest('.item-row').remove(); // use .closest() for improvement
  update_total();
});
```

So here i have delegated the event to `$(document)` but you can delegate to closest static parent that has to be your `table ID/className` or `table holder div's ID/className`.

---

And instead of `.parents()` use `.closest()` to get traversed up to the parent item.